# PHPStorm: how to suppress error message in code

Tags: phpstorm

PHPStorm's validator incorrectly detects error in PHP code. Code is valid and working. How to suppress that message?

[image]

UPD: Ok, I think someone assumpt there is useless code on screenshot and issue can be resolved by removing one. Below is a sample of usage:

```
class Singlton_Example extends DSCondition {

    use Instance;

    protected function __construct() {
        // ... some initialization here
    }
}

$test = Singleton_Example::instance();
```

Comment: I don't think you can instantiate a trait.

Comment: You cannot suppress it -- as far as I understand it the check is done at Anotator (parser?) level and not as separate Inspection (which you can turn off or silent it for 1 line). Your only option is to watch for this ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12145 and live with this error in PhpStorm until this ticket will be resolved.